# Google Custom Search (CSE) API returns error code 500 ({"error": {"code": 500, "message": null } })

Tags: google-custom-search

I use Google Custom Search API. url example;

https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=Api_Key&cx=Client_ID&q=Search_Keyword&alt=json&sort=date-sdate:d&lr=lang_tr&cr=countryTR

This url working correctly a year, but return error code 500 since last week. What is the reason for this error. Any one can help me?

note: There are no invoices outstanding

Comment: OP notes "There are no invoices outstanding" which hints at it, but I'll say it explicitly for posterity: It appears if your account is overdue, you will also get the 500-null response.

Answer (score 3):

We were also confronted by this problem. It seems that Google has changed its custom search API a bit on 2013-03-06.

We used to have the **cx ID** point to Google Custom Search API **project ID**. That no longer works and now gives this unhelpful *500 Internal Server Error* response:

```
{
 "error": {
  "code": 500,
  "message": null
 }
}
```

Based on our tests, here is how you can solve the problem:

1. create a new CSE engine at http://www.google.com/cse/all.
2. configure it: enable image search, check to use the whole web, if needed
3. click **Search Engine ID** button under search engine's *Setup* section. The new search engine ID is in form [~15 numbers]:[~10 letters and numbers] (e.g. *09238519823059291357:vsdoijv7svdkij7*).
4. Use this search engine ID as the **cx** parameter in API queries and it should work.

I hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but, for the record: I had this same result when I had a bug which created a `$` character as a parameter separator in the URL, instead of an `&`. So, it appears that a malformed query can also result in this error being returned.

Answer (score 0):

If account is expired error is again 500